# How to combine GROUP BY and ORDER BY here?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database with a table called 'messages'. The colums are 'sender', 'reseiver', 'subject', 'time' (the timestamp).

With my query, I want to get the entries grouped by the subject. **BUT** I want to have the corresponding time to be the latest.

So, for example, if this was my db:

```
person1   |   person2   |   hello   |   2019-06-24 20:0**7**:00
person2   |   person1   |   hello   |   2019-06-24 20:0**8**:00
```

I want to get this:

```
subject: hello
last entry: 2019-06-24 20:0**8**:00
```

I wasn't able to put the ORDER BY in front of the GROUP BY, so I tried a subquery:

```
SELECT subject, sender, receiver, time
FROM 
    (SELECT subject, sender, receiver, time
     FROM messages
     ORDER BY time DESC) AS subselect
GROUP BY subject
```

But it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Easy to do in MySQL 8.x. Not that easy in 5.x. Which MySQL version do you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Comment: Im using MySQL 5.7 :P

Comment: No it does not work.. if it executes you play russian roulette with you resultset.. on servers with enabled sql mode only_full_group_by this query will error because you misuse GROUP BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT subject,sender,reseiver,max(time) 
FROM messages
GROUP BY subject,sender,reseiver
ORDER BY max(time) DESC
```

You should group by sender,reseiver as well, otherwise those columns have unpredictable value. Or omit those column entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```sql
SELECT subject,sender,reseiver, MAX(time) AS time FROM messages GROUP BY subject
```

So, it works like this:

1. Gets relevant records (in this case -- all of them, as no `WHERE` provided)
2. Groups them by `subject` column, so now we have groups of records with the same subject
3. In every group it looks for max value of `time` column -- but this is per group, so, I guess that's what you wanted

And if you want to sort groups somehow, just add another `ORDER BY` at the end, without any subqueries.

Comment: No it does not work.. if it executes you play russian roulette with you resultset.. on servers with enabled sql mode only_full_group_by this query will error

Comment: `only_full_group_by` would fail for original query in the qustion too, so, irrelevant. Re roulette, agree, missed that part, I thought for some reason only time matters.

Comment: it's not irrelevant, the topicstarter or futher readers need to know what happens if they execute this kind of queries..

Comment: there is only one valid execption when this query is valid is when the message columns has a primary or unique key.. Then SQL 1999 standards optional feature which is called functional dependency which MySQL 5.7.5+ supports can be used.